# golang used waitGroup and still ended up with a deadlock error

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm trying to implement the bridge pattern following Go Concurrency book

```
func bridge_impl() {
    done := make(chan interface{})
    defer close(done)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    bridge := func(
        done <-chan interface{},
        chanStream <-chan <-chan interface{},
    ) <-chan interface{} {
        valStream := make(chan interface{})
        go func() {
            wg.Add(1)
            defer close(valStream)
            for {
                var stream <-chan interface{}
                select {
                case maybeStream, ok := <-chanStream:
                    fmt.Println("works")
                    if ok == false {
                        return
                    }
                    stream = maybeStream
                case <-done:
                    return
                }
                for val := range stream {
                    select {
                    case valStream <- val:
                    case <-done:
                    }
                }
            }
        }()
        return valStream
    }
    genVals := func() <-chan <-chan interface{} {
        chanStream := make(chan (<-chan interface{}))
        go func() {
            wg.Add(1)
            defer close(chanStream)
            for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
                stream := make(chan interface{})
                stream <- i
                close(stream)
                chanStream <- stream
            }
        }()
        return chanStream
    }
    for v := range bridge(done, genVals()) {
        fmt.Printf("%v ", v)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

However I'm receiving a deadlock error`all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` at first I thought I should add a waitgroup even though it wasn't implemented in the book example but I ended up with the same error

Comment: You can't add to the waitgroup from inside the goroutine which you are waiting on. The stack trace from the deadlock will show where all goroutines are blocked, and help diagnose what is waiting.

Comment: unfortunately, I moved it before calling the goroutine and i'm still having the same issue

Comment: Yes, that is not why it's blocked, it just makes their use invalid and may panic. The blocking can't be solved by the waitgroups alone, you need figure out where your synchronization is already blocking progress.

Comment: `stream := make(chan interface{})`; `stream<-i`; `close(stream)`; `chanStream <- stream`... This is so wrong. The second statement is blocking and no amount of waitgroups will unblock it. The 3rd and 4th statements will *never* be executed. And, even if it didn't block, the 4th statement doesn't make sense given that the 3rd closes the channel. Why send a closed channel?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for: https://go.dev/play/p/7D9OzrsvZyi

Comment: You're absolutely correct, the bridge acting as a consumer will first take in the channel of channels and then wait for a stream to be pushed. That was pretty insightful thanks. please do convert it to an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @Devchimp answer added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you do not need a WaitGroup at all, you just need to re-order the statements in the `genVals` function's loop:

```golang
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    stream := make(chan interface{})
    chanStream <- stream
    stream <- i
    close(stream)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/7D9OzrsvZyi

Answer (score 2):

There are two main issues.
[*Working example*](https://go.dev/play/p/BKL0ofNky6w)

**First issue**:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    stream := make(chan interface{})
    stream <- i
    close(stream)
    chanStream <- stream
}
```

writing to unbuffered channel after creation with no goroutine reading. Use buffered channel or another goroutine.

```
stream := make(chan interface{}, 1) // buffer size 1 to not block `stream <- i`
```

**Second issue**:
Using `wg.Add(1)` without `wg.Done()`.
You can use `defer` in both cases.

```
wg.Add(1)
defer wg.Done()
```